# Deciding what to write in CMakeLists.txt - mainly in subfolders

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a simple project going that uses CMake and gtest. I have a basic CMakeLists.txt file working, but I want to get a better understanding of how to use multiple CMakeLists.txt's and connect them. The code so far for the project is like this:

https://github.com/dmonopoly/writeart/tree/10b62048e6eb6a6ddd0658123d85ce4f5f601178

For quicker reference, the only CMakeLists.txt file (in the project root) that I take advantage of has this inside:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

# Options
option(TEST "Build all tests." OFF) # makes boolean 'TEST' available

# Make PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR, PROJECT_BINARY_DIR, and PROJECT_NAME available
set(PROJECT_NAME MyProject)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g") # -Wall")

#set(COMMON_INCLUDES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include) if you want your own include/ directory
# then you can do include_directories(${COMMON_INCLUDES}) in other cmakelists.txt files

################################
# Normal Libraries & Executables
################################
add_library(standard_lib Standard.cpp Standard.h)
add_library(converter_lib Converter.cpp Converter.h)
add_executable(main Main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(main standard_lib converter_lib)

################################
# Testing
################################
if (TEST)
    # This adds another subdirectory, which has project(gtest)
    add_subdirectory(lib/gtest-1.6.0)

    enable_testing()

    # Include the gtest library
    # gtest_SOURCE_DIR is available due to project(gtest) above
    include_directories(${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${gtest_SOURCE_DIR})

    ##############
    # Unit Tests
    ##############
    # Naming
    set(UNIT_TESTS runUnitTests)

    add_executable(${UNIT_TESTS} ConverterTest.cpp)

    # standard linking to gtest stuff
    target_link_libraries(${UNIT_TESTS} gtest gtest_main)

    # extra linking for the project
    target_link_libraries(${UNIT_TESTS} standard_lib converter_lib)

    # This is so you can do 'make test' to see all your tests run, instead of manually running the executable runUnitTests to see those specific tests.
    add_test(NAME myUnitTests COMMAND runUnitTests)
endif()
```

**My goal is to move Standard.cpp and Standard.h into lib/.** The moment I do this, though, I find the ordering of what I do in my CMakeLists.txt complicated. I need the library for my gtest setup, but the library would have to get made in lib/CMakeLists.txt, right? Wouldn't it easily become really complicated to find where all your libraries are and executables are as you would have to look through all your CMakeLists.txt's?

If I am missing something conceptually, or if there is a good example I could use to solve this easily, that would be great.

Help appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to (and probably shouldn't) include the contents of `build` in your `git` repository.

Comment: Well the project was partly for demonstration/teaching purposes, too... unless there's something security-wise that is bad about it, I thought it was okay.

Comment: Everything in the `build` dir is generated by `cmake` - changing a build option changes a bunch of the generated files (so every recompile makes the `git` repo "dirty"). Because they're all auto-generated, there's not a whole lot of *point* to having them in version control. Your `build` directory won't necessarily have a valid executable for the next person to `pull` it, so it might all get overwritten anyway. But... aside from that, there's nothing wrong with doing it. I should have left my comment as "you don't need to..." :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use multiple `CMakeLists.txt` files, don't.

```
################################
# Normal Libraries & Executables
################################

add_library(standard_lib lib/Standard.cpp lib/Standard.h)
add_library(converter_lib lib/Converter.cpp lib/Converter.h)

# Main.cpp needs to know where "Standard.h" is for the #include, 
#   so we tell it to search this directory too. 
include_directories(lib)
```

If you do want multiple `CMakeLists.txt`, you'd move it out:

```
# Main CMakeLists.txt:
add_subdirectory(lib)

include_directories (${standard_lib_SOURCE_DIR}/standard_lib) 

link_directories (${standard_lib_BINARY_DIR}/standard_lib)
```

and in `/lib/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_library (standard_lib Standard.cpp)
```

Here's [an example](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/examples.html).

Comment: This is a great solution for smaller to medium sized projects (which I use as well). But it starts to become a problem when you decide to "modularize" your libraries. E.g. when you start a second project which uses 'converter', but does not need standard or gtest.

Comment: Is it reasonable to only use the root CMakeLists.txt and do everything from there? First of all, is that possible, and second, if so, doesn't this make it much cleaner - or at least, all of the linking and executable creation and etc. are all together in one file, so we wouldn't have to search across multiple files to find how the files all connected. And, as @Andre says, would it avoid the problem of when a second project wants to use a particular library alone?

Comment: @dmonopoly It's reasonable to do, especially for smaller or medium-sized projects. Having a clear separation between the libraries (in different `CMakeLists.txt` files) makes it easier, in my (limited) experience, at splitting a project into sub-projects - for smaller projects, though, this generally isn't that big a deal.